# Upgrade to Quartz 2.2 JDBC Jobstore new Column Sched_time

Tags: java, jdbc, quartz-scheduler, upgrade

I am currently upgrading Quartz to version 2.2. Therefore I had to do some migrations on the Tables which are used by the JDBCJobstore.

For the table "qrtz_fired_triggers" there was added the column "sched_time" with a Not Null constraint.

Actually I now ran into the issue, that there is an entry in this table, which results in, that I can't add the NotNull constraint.

Does anyone have a clue, what a possible default value for this column could be, without breaking the functionallity of Quartz?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do in this situation if at all possible is to do a clean shutdown of quartz that will wait for all currently executing jobs to finish, and thereby ensure that the fired triggers table is empty: "scheduler.shutdown(true)”.  If that isn’t possible in your environment the best thing you can do would be to set the sched_time column for the rows that do exist to the same value as the fired_time column.